# disable other button in a buttonGroup when clicks one button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax

I have an array of data

```
const projectTypeValues = [
{ name: 'Hour', value: 'hour'},
{ name: 'Day', value: 'day'},
{ name: 'Session', value: 'session'},
{ name: 'project', value: 'project'}]
```

From there I am showing the buttons in a material ui buttonGroup through an loop.

```
{projectTypeValues.map(element=>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary">{element.name}</Button>
        )}
```

how do i implement an onClick function that will make the other buttons in the loop disable except the one that was clicked?

Comment: Add data-attribute to button, after load page (so button exist in html) addEventListener with querySelectorAll and create your own function.

Comment: You can add `disabled` attribute based on your condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage it by storing a selected button value in state and checking on `disabled` time. You can use the button `disabled` attribute for disabling. You can store `unique` value for matching button disable like `name` or `id`.

If we use `name` for selecting the button so we need to check like this way.

```
disabled={currentSelect && currentSelect !== element.name}
```

**Example:**

```js
const projectTypeValues = [
  { name: "Hour", value: "hour" },
  { name: "Day", value: "day" },
  { name: "Session", value: "session" },
  { name: "project", value: "project" }
];
const App = () => {
  const [currentSelect, setSelect] = React.useState(null);
  console.log(currentSelect);
  return (
    <div>
      {projectTypeValues.map((element) => (
        <div style={{ padding: "10px" }} key={element.name}>
          <button
            disabled={currentSelect && currentSelect !== element.name}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => setSelect(element.name)}
          >
            {element.name}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script
  crossorigin
  src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"
></script>
<script
  crossorigin
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
function App() {
    const [disable, setDisable] = React.useState(false);

 return (
        <button variant="contained" color="primary" 
         disabled={disable} onClick={() => 
         setDisable(true)}>
         {element.name} 
        </button>
         );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a `state` for the selected button, something like this:

`const [selectedButtonIndex, setSelectedButtonIndex] = useState(-1)`

then you need to use `map` and get the index and `disable` or other buttons:

```
 {projectTypeValues.map((element, index)=>
          <Button variant="contained" disabled={index !== -1 && index !== selectedButtonIndex} onClick={() => setSelectedButtonIndex(index)} color="primary">{element.name</Button>
 )}
```

Note: I started with `-1` as initial value, as this enables all buttons initially and then it locks your choice. You could use another state to signal the fact that a choice has been made.